# Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Linq.IQueryable' to 'System.Collections.Generic.List'

Tags: c#

What's wrong with this code?

```
List<CampaignManager_tbl> candidates = new List<CampaignManager_tbl>();

        candidates = from cat in db.Events_Category_tbl
                     join can in db.Candidates_Info_tbl on cat.events_category_id equals can.events_category_id
                     where cat.events_info_id == events.events_info_id
                     select new CampaignManager_tbl {
                         events_category_name = cat.events_category_name,
                         candidates_fullname = can.candidates_fullname,
                         candidates_place = can.candidates_place
                     };

        return View(candidates);
```

It works when I query only one table using this method,but when I try this one. It is not working.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to convert your `IQueryable` to a `List`. You can do this by adding `.ToList()` at the end of your Linq query.

```
List<CampaignManager_tbl> candidates = new List<CampaignManager_tbl>();

candidates = (from cat in db.Events_Category_tbl
                  join can in db.Candidates_Info_tbl on cat.events_category_id equals can.events_category_id
                  where cat.events_info_id == events.events_info_id
                  select new CampaignManager_tbl {
                         events_category_name = cat.events_category_name,
                         candidates_fullname = can.candidates_fullname,
                         candidates_place = can.candidates_place
                  }).ToList();

return View(candidates);
```

Comment: @Mayank It doesn't have to be of type var. This is converting a `IQueryable<CampaingManager_tbl>` to a `List<CampaingManager_tbl>`.

Comment: oh yaaa...  sorry... i didn't focus on first line... thanks @Loetn

Answer (score 0):

Another answer was already accepted but I wanted to post my resolution in case it helps someone with my specific situation and because it's now 2022:

```
public List<SalesIOsmenu> GetCollectionListData(int classId, int marketId)
        {
            //Get all Collections matching dropdown selections
            List<SalesIOsmenu> collectionList = new List<SalesIOsmenu>();

            collectionList = db.SalesIOsmenus.Where(m => m.MarketId == marketId
                                                            && m.ClassId == classId).ToList();

            return collectionList;
        }
```

Adding ToList() after the query fixed it.  I get a nice clean object to return.